# Lower level htaccess does not override root htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

After two days I'm all out of ideas. I have an htaccess file inside "public_html" which appears to ignore other htaccess files in sub-directories. The purpose of the two htaccess files is to password protect different areas with diffrent passwords.

The problem: once I gain access via password to "public_html", I automatically have access to any other sub-directory despite the fact that those are password protected with their own htaccess.

Thank you for any clues you may provide!

Paul.

Comment: Did you check your settings for [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, AllowOverride is a setting in Apache that allows the use of .htaccess.  Given that the htaccess file in the root directory works just fine, I assume AllowOverride is not the issue. Or is there more to it?

Comment: The root .htaccess can redefine AllowOverride to disable further overrides in nested dirs. It's the only thing I can think of without looking into the entire configuration in detail, and of course checking Apache logs.